# Synchronize contents of JEditorPane between two JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am working on a Java Swing application (JDK 7). I have two JEditorPane instances on two different JFrames, that I need to synchronize. I know the hard way of force copying contents on a modified event is one way to do it. But, I was wondering if there is a smarter/easier way to do this. I tried to use the same JEditorPane instances on both the frames, but that did not work.

I believe a reference to the container panel is included in the JEditorPane instance, so the old container is erased when it is added to a new container. Can we create a new subclass of JEditorPane, that can accommodate two containers?

Have you tried something like this before?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 2 instances of `JEditorPane`. Set them the same `EditorKit` and then use `Document` from the first one in the second.

```
editorPane2.setDocument(editorPane1.getDocument());
```

`Document` is a model in fact and you can share the same model between 2 components.